# Why am I not notified and my reputation is not increasing when my comment is upvoted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment, reputation, notifications

I had an [upvote of a comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261603/is-there-a-non-parametric-equivalent-of-factorial-manova-at-least-2x2/261612#261612) but I did not see it, neither in my Inbox nor in reputation. Is it normal?

Reputation is less important, compared to not seeing this activity in my Inbox.

Comment: Your link does not go to any contribution of yours that affects reputation.  If you're referring to an upvote on a *comment,* that's worthless.  Consult the help at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation.

Comment: Ok, I said, that reputation it is not crucial (I don't know when it increase in details), but it was not in inbox or in other place. In this case it is not important, but I am afraid to loose some interesting events. The question is should I be somehow informed about up-voting and new comment on not my Answer or question, or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ask about earning reputation for posting comments.  Because comments are "second-class citizens" on SE, they do not accrue reputation and you are not notified of votes on them.  The only thing they can actually do for you is earn you the [Commentator Badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges) and [Pundit Badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit). By virtue of their absence, they can indirectly help others earn the [Tumbleweed badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed).

Comment: @Andre Thank you for the clarification.  I'll remove that last sentence since it's outdated.

Comment: Thanks everybody for explanations. Upvotes of this question should not be in my reputation because it is meta?

Comment: That is correct: because voting here on Meta tends to reflect approval or disagreement rather than quality of posts, it is not tracked for reputation.  You still earn badges (FWIW).  Your constructive participation on Meta really matters only if you wish to be elected as a moderator.